# Optimization tips and guidelines for xml parsing on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xml-parsing, xmpp

I am looking for optimization tips and guidelines for xml parsing on ios. I am using currently KissXML in one of my projects to parse  messages in about 50 Hz. With this rate, i can see clearly that the high processing load to process the messages even with relatively short messages (about 10 elements).

One of the optimization strategies is of course selecting the "right" parser. A detailed comparison between the available parsers for ios can be found here http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project.

However, I am currently trying to investigate general guidelines and tips on how to optimize by payloads to increase the performance as possible. I hope that experts do have some say about this! Any individual or partial tips are very much appreciated.

Comment: Any thought is appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

As for tips not directly involving parsing XML, but that can still help you out on that task:

1. Doing the parsing in a background thread, can easily help you out. With GCD you can define the priority of the thread as well.
2. You can use a technique from [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/ObjCRuntimeGuide.pdf) Apple document. On page 14 you can read:

> Using methodForSelector: to circumvent dynamic binding saves most of
>   the time required by messaging. However, the savings will be
>   significant only where a particular message is repeated many times, as
>   in the for loop shown above.

I have actually used this technique in setting a value on an array of objects and I was able to get 0.7 seconds improvement. Might not be much, but in heavier and repetitive tasks I do think it will make a difference.

Comment: thanks for your contribution to this question. It is very strange for me that I did not get much input on this even though I think it is quite an important question.

Comment: I do think so as well. But for most people, a parser that actually gets the job done is enough.